# Android Jetpack AppCompatTextView.setTypeface StackOverFlowError because of an infinite loop

Tags: android, android-jetpack

We have been receiving some crashes about this occasion: when we use the attribute `android:textStyle` in an AppCompatTextView with any value (bold, italic or both), or setting a value for `android:fontFamily`, on Android 4.2.2 version it loops in itself that eventually causes **StackOverFlowError**.

Here is an example of how we use the views.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/welcome_app_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

And here is one of the exceptions:

```
Caused by java.lang.StackOverflowError
       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java)
       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:629)
       at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompatBaseImpl.getUniqueKey(TypefaceCompatBaseImpl.java:85)
       at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompatBaseImpl.getFontFamily(TypefaceCompatBaseImpl.java:210)
       at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompat.getBestFontFromFamily(TypefaceCompat.java:169)
       at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompat.create(TypefaceCompat.java:196)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:702)
       at android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(TextView.java:1581)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:705)
       at android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(TextView.java:1581)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:705)
       at android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(TextView.java:1581)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:705)
       at android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(TextView.java:1581)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:705)
       at android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(TextView.java:1581)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:705)
       at android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(TextView.java:1581)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:705)
       at android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(TextView.java:1581)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:705)
       at android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(TextView.java:1581)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:705)
       at android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(TextView.java:1581)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:705)
       at android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(TextView.java:1581)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:705)
       at android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(TextView.java:1581)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:705)
       at android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(TextView.java:1581)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:705)
       at android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(TextView.java:1581)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:705)
       at android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(TextView.java:1581)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:705)
       at android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(TextView.java:1581)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:705)
       at android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(TextView.java:1581)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:705)
       at android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(TextView.java:1581)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:705)
       at android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(TextView.java:1581)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:705)
       at android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(TextView.java:1581)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:705)
       at android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(TextView.java:1581)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:705)
       at android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(TextView.java:1581)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:705)
       at android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(TextView.java:1581)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:705)
       at android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(TextView.java:1581)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:705)
       at android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(TextView.java:1581)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:705)
       at android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(TextView.java:1581)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:705)
       at android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(TextView.java:1581)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:705)
       at android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(TextView.java:1581)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:705)
       at android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(TextView.java:1581)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:705)
       at android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(TextView.java:1581)

// it goes on like this forever until it reaches to Activity.setContentView()
```

It might be even on some specific devices because we are not able to locally reproduce this issue. **Besides removing the text style**, what can be done to solve this issue? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Report the issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=460343). Make a sample project that reproduces the issue and post instructions how to trigger it. Make sure to specify what version of AndroidX components you're using and what version of Android this happens on.

Comment: That's the problem, we cannot reproduce this locally so I can't really create a sample project for it. This is a report from Crashlytics from an app that is in production.

Comment: Then share the complete crash report, perhaps this can be tracked to a specific device. (And really mention the AndroidX components version because that's not written anywhere. All the info can help here as well.)

Comment: Will do. Hopefully it'll help because source codes aren't taking me anywhere.

Comment: Is the app using dynamic features?

Comment: @DeividasStrioga I've also received a crash report like this, and I'm not using dynamic features. It was also on Android 4.2.2 (Lenovo S930), but it originated in a different place. Here's an abbreviated stack trace (bottom-up): `TextView.performLongClick ... Editor$HandleView.showActionPopupWindow ... Editor$ActionPopupWindow.initContentView ... LayoutInflater.inflate ... AppCompatViewInflater.createTextView ... TextView.<init>, TextView.setTypefaceFromAttrs, AppCompatTextView.setTypeface, TextView.setTypeface`, and then the last two repeat as above.

Comment: @FurkanYurdakul If you can't reproduce it, then how do you know it's related to `textStyle` and `fontFamily`?

Comment: @mhsmith I don't know for certain but I'm going with my gut at this point. Considering in our code we aren't calling "setTypeface" manually, the only places that the Android framework will call it is either `android:fontFamily` or `android:textStyle`.

Comment: @FurkanYurdakul did you manage to find a solution? Is there any bug reported? I'm having the same issue on Lenovo and some Samsung devices.

Comment: @AhmadulHoq Unfortunately, no. Sorry. Since the error percentage is pretty low, we decided to ignore the exceptions at this point. If I find a solution, I will post it as an answer here.